# Is it important to quiet lock the mutex?

Tags: debugging, synchronization, pthreads, embedded, ipc

I have the following code in my project.

```
synch_MutexLock_Quiet(s_mutex_reg);  
retval=function();  
synch_MutexUnlock_Quiet(s_mutex_reg);
```

I understand the concept of mutex and I googled for understanding the Quiet   feature.It is seen from the man pages for mutex() as

> MTX_QUIET This option is used to quiet logging messages during
>   individual mutex operations. This can be used to trim superfluous
>   logging messages for debugging purposes.

I do not understand the advantage of turning off the logging messages at any stage during debugging.
Please explain when this would be necessary

Comment: Most debugging on embedded targets take up finite space, so it can be nice to be able to disable logging on selected primitives.

Comment: By "I am not getting the advantage", do you actually mean that you have observed or gained no advantage, or did you really mean "I do not understand the advantage". Just like in programming, clear semantics is important in English, especially where the intended meaning cannot be distinguished by context or vocal intonation, as is the case here.  That is to say, you cannot always write it as you would say it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion .What I really I meant is "I do not understand the advantage".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mutex lock and unlock is already an expensive operation on an embedded device, and logging even more so in many cases. Secondly, storage capacity is often quite constrained, whether logs are going to a flash memory device or into RAM somewhere.

Comment: The mutex locks are potentially high priority scenarios  which should not   be avoided while debugging the code is what I am thinking.